# Received a badge (vox populi) I shouldn't have

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I just got a notification that I received the Vox Populi (use 40 votes in one day) badge, but my user page shows I've only made 2 votes today (which sounds about right; I certainly didn't vote on 40 questions and answers today).  Is anyone else getting a notification like this?

Comment: Ok, so a *bug* is [status-bydesign]? How does that work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We just deployed a change that affects the voting badges.  This is why you see a number of these badges being awarded.

For more information about this change, you can see [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/123048/140548).

Note that there is a bug with Vox Populi only that is awarding too many of them, beyond the expected more for retroactive awards, and a fix is being deployed now.  The erroneous awards there will be cleaned up shortly.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. I got he notification too and thought it was weird and worried someone was using my account. Hopefully its just a bug.

Comment: Exactly what I was worried about :)